# Can we have option to sort flag summary?

Tags: feature-request, flags

Over at `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/#userid`, you can see the posts that you have flagged. This is a nice feature, and it even shows you the stats on all of them.

> [image]

But why is there no way to sort this massive list? Time is useful when I want to see the most recent posts that I have flagged, but when I want to see the ones that are being disputed, I don't want to find each one manually. I want to be able to easy sort this. So I am proposing a sorting option similar to that of the badge page.

[image]

As an alternative, each of the stats could be a link, and clicking on them would show the respective flags

Comment: +1 , I too want this feature.